# Versions of Kdenlive in official repositories are deprecated

Tags: versions, kdenlive

On [Kdenlive's official download page for Ubuntu](http://kdenlive.org/download-ubuntu) they said this exact statement.

Firstly what exactly does that mean? And why and how is that??

Answer (score 1):

That means that the versions you can find in the Software Centre are out of date. This is possibly because they have updated it, but not got it into the repos.

Comment: hmmm well why don't they simply update the packages in the main repos? I have a feeling that there's a story behind this

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know that much into it... It could be that they weren't allowed for some reason.

Comment: Many packages don't have dedicated Ubuntu maintainer. Many packages are from the Debian archives and recompiled with the Ubuntu. With the Kdenlive the latest changelog is telling: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/k/kdenlive/kdenlive_0.9.6-5ubuntu1/changelog: 'Merge from Debian unstable' . Both the Debian and the Ubuntu are short of packagers, testers, etc...

Comment: and more of the Debian and the Debian KDE team: http://blogs.fsfe.org/mario/?p=231

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software